# Is google case sensitive?

Tags: google-search

I noticed that when I type "SoC" or "soc", the results are not the same. But I read on Quora that Google is case sensitive. I don't know what to think ?

Notice : I'm in France

Edit: sorry I wanted to write "But I read on Quora that Google is **NOT** case sensitive"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No.

---

#### It's not case-sensitive.

First of all, when I searched `soc` or `SoC` the results were the same, in the first and second page. So it's weird that in your case they weren't. Maybe there's something specific that cause this.

Here's an answer from a [Google employee on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Google-search-case-sensitive/answer/Paul-Haahr):

> I work on search at Google and I can confirm Seth's answer:  Google search is not case sensitive, whether words are in quotes or not.
>
> To give a little background as to why, you can find good reasons based on both efficiency and user experience.  Users tend to just type their searches in lower case and a search engine wouldn't want to hurt those searches or require users to think about what case to use.  The cost of using case information during searches is also high compared to how much difference it would make in practice.

- This answer was up-voted by two other Google employees.

#### Is there something that `is` case-sensitive?

The things that are case-sensitive are special search operators such as `OR`, `AND`.

If you search for `dog or cat` the results would be related to things between dogs and cats, such as comparisons and etc.

If you search for `dog OR cat` the results would be about things related to dogs, aside to things related to cats. Like combining the results from searching `dog` and searching `cat` separately.